# How to always receive newest packet using MulticastSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, client, multicast

I have a program in Java that implements `MulticastSocket`, in order to perform network discovery. The problem is, the server sends out several packets with a Serialized `ArrayList` of active shares every 5 seconds to a specific port (in my case, 4446) and then the clients receive that. However, if the `ArrayList` is modified, the server sends it out on the next send, but the client, when it receives, receives the old packages that the server already sent out a long time ago.

Here's an example:

`ArrayList` has 1 element.

Server -> sending - > wait 5 seconds -> sending packet #2 -> wait 5 seconds -> *modified `ArrayList` during time frame* -> sending packet #3

Client -> looks for active shares -> receiving packet #1 -> 1 element! OK!
... (can wait for an indefinite amount of time - by this time #2 and #3 have been sent by the server)

Client -> looks for active shares -> receiving #packet 2 -> 1 element. NO.

And that's where all consistency is lost, because it should have (ideally) received packet #3.

Is there any way to make it so that the clients always receive the most updated packet sent? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Multicast, like UDP, is not like TCP there is no guarantee of delivery, or order of delivery for that matter, to the client. It's possible that the client is throwing out the data before receipt if you're not getting #3.

I would double check your assumptions on the operation of your client/server code.

Are you losing packet #3 or you just want that delivered before #2 and to disregard #2? If it's the second case, you're going to need to write your code in such away as to collect all the packets as quickly as possible. An option would be to immediately try to receive() after you receive a packet in a loop, with a very low timeout. This may mean adjusting your so_timeout, which means a kernel round trip, and doing that for every packet, would be expensive.

A better way would be to have a thread that is constantly reading from the socket, and for every packet put it into a BlockingQueue which another processing thread reads from. In this way you wouldn't have to care much about the timeout on the receive, and since it's just consuming you'd get the packets as quickly as the jvm can read it from the socket.

Answer (score 0):

This is an inherent race condition in network communications. Data source changes state while its previous report is in transit to the receivers - at this point you want to reverse the time and update the data that is already on the wire. I haven't found any handy library that could do that, so I would suggest you just process your packets in order :)

The real answer here is proper [*communication protocol*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_protocol). Not the transport like TCP or UDP, but your own *application-level protocol*. Though take a look at the [TCP state transition diagram](http://www4.cs.fau.de/Projects/JX/Projects/TCP/tcpstate.html) for a great example and inspiration - it shows that you can treat a rather complex problem as a manageable state machine. Define states at both client and server sides, define your events and transitions, and code accordingly.